# Python Sockets - Closing Threads to allow more users

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

My current code is as follows:

```
from socket import *
import threading
import datetime
import csv
import time

global clist
clist = []

HOST = "ip"
PORT = 1876
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT)) 
s.listen(5)

def clientHandler():
    print("Thread successful\n")
    connect, address = s.accept()
    clist.append(connect)
    iplist = open("iplist.txt","a+")
    iplist.write(str(address)+"\n")
    iplist.close()
    print('IP Recorded.')
    while 1:
        try:
            data = connect.recv(1024)
            data = data.decode()
            current_date = time.strftime("%d-%m")
            log = open(current_date+"log.txt","a+")
            print("("+time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")+")","> ", data)
            log.write("> "+data+"\n")
            log.close()
            data = data.encode()
            for item in clist:
                item.sendall(data)
        except: #handles clients leaving and fixes reconnect bug, succesfully removing them from clist
            clist.remove(connect)
            print(address, 'has disconnected.')
            break



print("Server started...")
for i in range(5):
    makeThread = threading.Thread(target=clientHandler)
    makeThread.start()


aliveList = threading.enumerate()
print(aliveList)
```

My problem is that once clients join or rejoin (x5) the server won't allow any more connections (because the threads of my clientHandler function have been used). Would I have to close the threads and some how make them reusable to allow more clients to join/rejoin? (How would I do this?)
Also, could anybody recommend improvements to my code/guide me on the right path with socket programming, as I am very new to all this.

All help appreciated,

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `threading.activeCount()` to enumerate your threads.
Lets say you want 5 clients max , then `activeCount()` should be <= 6 ( five clients and the main thread )
Try this loop :

```
while True : 
    try : 
        if threading.activeCount() < 6 : 
            makeThread = threading.Thread(target=clientHandler)
            #makeThread.daemon = True  ## uncomment this line if you want your threads to terminate when the main thread dies ##
            makeThread.start()
            print('Active clients: {}'.format(threading.activeCount() - 1))
    except KeyboardInterrupt : 
        print('terminated')
        break
```

Now when `clientHandler()` returns , there is room for the next client .

Comment: Hi t.m.adam sorry for the late reply, I tried what you said but it still only allows 5 clients to connect and then no more can connect even if they disconnected. Any more help would be golden, thanks

Comment: Updated again to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` ( if you want to break the loop ) , and fixed the `makeThread.daemon` issue

Comment: Appreciate the help bro, if you wouldn't mind could I add you on Skype to message as I'm new to networking but could really use this help!

Comment: Sorry , i don't have an account, but we could chat on [chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) . Also there are some very good online books about python sockets , and you can find some tutorials [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm) and [here](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/)

Comment: that would be great, i've never used chat.stackoverflow what room shall I go in?